# Recover data from unbootable Ubuntu VM on Hyper-V

Tags: boot, server

OK,
First off, I am a complete novice.  I can run updates and I can kind of change directories.  That's it, you will have to explain things to me like I am a child....

I have a Ubuntu 18.04.6 VM on WS2016 host through Hyper-V.
A few weeks ago it failed to boot after a power outage.  it stopped at "started user manager UID125"

I finally figured out how to get into rescue mode and someone recommended I try reinstalling GRUB which I somehow did successfully and it seems to make it past the original error but now hangs on a number of different things, never the same one twice.

This is for my Plex server and I have backups of all the media but not of the media servers metadata.  Yah, I know, I'm a bad boy....  I want to either recover the whole VM or just the server metadata to transfer to a new VM, I'm not picky.  If all else fails i will just scrap the whole thing and start from scratch.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Edited the title to match the question

Comment: I installed ubuntu-18.04.6-live-server-amd64 as a VM.  It worked flawlessly for about 3 years with periodic updates.  I did install Gnome initially as I am not very competent at CLI.
As I said, the initial point at which boot froze was "Started user manager uid 125"
After i reinstalled/upgraded to the latest version of GRUB it started hanging randomly.  Sometimes it says "Started GOME Display Manager.eport Generation.t Kernel crash Signatures...d. Shut Down...."  But mostly on the same original message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assumed that there was an issue with gnome because the error I was getting so I went into rescue mode and tried to reinstall it.  After that I just did a regular update/upgrade when i noticed a boot file threw an error.  After a quick search someone suggested to delete the file and let it be reinstalled.  As soon as I did that my server booted up like normal!